# compiling cocos2d-x for android

Tags: android, eclipse, cocos2d-x

Did a project on the cocos2d-x for ios. Now try to run it for android.Sobirayu using eclipse. Eliminated like all the mistakes and now he writes:

```
**** Build of configuration Default for project Cut2 ****

bash /Users/Banck/cocos2d-x-2.2-2.1/projects/Cut2/proj.android/build_native.sh 
NDK_ROOT = /Users/Banck/Downloads/android-ndk-r9b
COCOS2DX_ROOT = /Users/Banck/cocos2d-x-2.2-2.1/projects/Cut2/proj.android/../../..
APP_ROOT = /Users/Banck/cocos2d-x-2.2-2.1/projects/Cut2/proj.android/..
APP_ANDROID_ROOT = /Users/Banck/cocos2d-x-2.2-2.1/projects/Cut2/proj.android
Using prebuilt externals
Android NDK: WARNING: APP_PLATFORM android-19 is larger than android:minSdkVersion 8 in ./AndroidManifest.xml    
Android NDK: WARNING:/Users/Banck/cocos2d-x-2.2-2.1/projects/Cut2/proj.android/../../../cocos2dx/Android.mk:cocos2dx_static: LOCAL_LDLIBS is always ignored for static libraries    
make: Entering directory `/Users/Banck/cocos2d-x-2.2-2.1/projects/Cut2/proj.android'
[armeabi] Install        : libcocos2dcpp.so => libs/armeabi/libcocos2dcpp.so
make: Leaving directory `/Users/Banck/cocos2d-x-2.2-2.1/projects/Cut2/proj.android'

**** Build Finished ****
```

And that takes a message you need to fix what is wrong.But what's wrong? It seems to be all right already ... Advice please

Comment: It seems alright, what exactly do you need help with here?

Answer (score 0):

It seems ok, you just need to use this 'ant debug' command to generate an .apk package for you.